# Is there a Azure RateCard, which shows the MeterRates for all Linux OS (especially RHEL)?

Tags: java, azure, rhel, ratecard-api

I "download" a RateCard with the Azure REST Api because I need the VM's prices. Any VM is two times in the RateCard. One time with the Windows OS and one time with the Linux Ubuntu. I only need the VMs with Linux RHEL but these are not in the RateCard. It's important because the price is different.

Currently i use this URL for the REST Api:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=...&$filter=OfferDurableId eq '...' and Currency eq '...' and Locale eq '...' and RegionInfo eq '...'
```

Is there maybe an different Api i can use to get these specific informations?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two REST APIs for Azure Billing.

1. [Get price and metadata information for resources used in an Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt219004(v%3Dazure.100)), to get the price list of all Azure services.
2. [Get consumption data for an Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt219001(v%3Dazure.100)), to get the usage detail of the instances of Azure services you have used.

A solution is to get the usage details and filter it by the `instanceData` value if you have already a list of your RHEL Linux VM names, then you can look up the related ratecards by the same property `MeterId` of the filtered usage results. After that, you will find out there is the same ratecard for the same `MeterId` of Linux VM.